# LP_RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER_Array_5 error when initializing SAPNWRFC on Windows Python

Tags: python, windows, ctypes, saprfc

I got this code in https://blogs.sap.com/2014/08/29/how-to-use-actual-sap-netweaver-rfc-library-with-python-read-table/

I did all the procedures to run it and it works on windows, but when I put it on linux it doesn't work, the only thing I changed in the code for linux was to replace `windll.LoadLibrary(SAPNWRFC)` por `cdll.LoadLibrary(SAPNWRFC)`.

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    data = dataProcessing("USR01")
  File "src/utils.py", line 4, in dataProcessing
    queryData = query(table)
  File "src/readTable.py", line 9, in query
    hRFC = SAP.RfcOpenConnection(connection(), 5, RfcErrInf)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER_Array_5 instance instead of RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER_Array_5
```

The code:

```
from ctypes import *
import platform, os

#-Structures------------------------------------------------------------
class RFC_ERROR_INFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("code", c_long),
                ("group", c_long),
                ("key", c_wchar * 128),
                ("message", c_wchar * 512),
                ("abapMsgClass", c_wchar * 21),
                ("abapMsgType", c_wchar * 2),
                ("abapMsgNumber", c_wchar * 4),
                ("abapMsgV1", c_wchar * 51),
                ("abapMsgV2", c_wchar * 51),
                ("abapMsgV3", c_wchar * 51),
                ("abapMsgV4", c_wchar * 51)]

class RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("name", c_wchar_p),
                ("value", c_wchar_p)]

#-Constants-------------------------------------------------------------

#-RFC_RC - RFC return codes---------------------------------------------
RFC_OK = 0
RFC_COMMUNICATION_FAILURE = 1
RFC_LOGON_FAILURE = 2
RFC_ABAP_RUNTIME_FAILURE = 3
RFC_ABAP_MESSAGE = 4
RFC_ABAP_EXCEPTION = 5
RFC_CLOSED = 6
RFC_CANCELED = 7
RFC_TIMEOUT = 8
RFC_MEMORY_INSUFFICIENT = 9
RFC_VERSION_MISMATCH = 10
RFC_INVALID_PROTOCOL = 11
RFC_SERIALIZATION_FAILURE = 12
RFC_INVALID_HANDLE = 13
RFC_RETRY = 14
RFC_EXTERNAL_FAILURE = 15
RFC_EXECUTED = 16
RFC_NOT_FOUND = 17
RFC_NOT_SUPPORTED = 18
RFC_ILLEGAL_STATE = 19
RFC_INVALID_PARAMETER = 20
RFC_CODEPAGE_CONVERSION_FAILURE = 21
RFC_CONVERSION_FAILURE = 22
RFC_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL = 23
RFC_TABLE_MOVE_BOF = 24
RFC_TABLE_MOVE_EOF = 25
RFC_START_SAPGUI_FAILURE = 26
RFC_ABAP_CLASS_EXCEPTION = 27
RFC_UNKNOWN_ERROR = 28
RFC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE = 29

#-RFCTYPE - RFC data types----------------------------------------------
RFCTYPE_CHAR = 0
RFCTYPE_DATE = 1
RFCTYPE_BCD = 2
RFCTYPE_TIME = 3
RFCTYPE_BYTE = 4
RFCTYPE_TABLE = 5
RFCTYPE_NUM = 6
RFCTYPE_FLOAT = 7
RFCTYPE_INT = 8
RFCTYPE_INT2 = 9
RFCTYPE_INT1 = 10
RFCTYPE_NULL = 14
RFCTYPE_ABAPOBJECT = 16
RFCTYPE_STRUCTURE = 17
RFCTYPE_DECF16 = 23
RFCTYPE_DECF34 = 24
RFCTYPE_XMLDATA = 28
RFCTYPE_STRING = 29
RFCTYPE_XSTRING = 30
RFCTYPE_BOX = 31
RFCTYPE_GENERIC_BOX = 32

#-RFC_UNIT_STATE - Processing status of a background unit---------------
RFC_UNIT_NOT_FOUND = 0 
RFC_UNIT_IN_PROCESS = 1 
RFC_UNIT_COMMITTED = 2 
RFC_UNIT_ROLLED_BACK = 3 
RFC_UNIT_CONFIRMED = 4 

#-RFC_CALL_TYPE - Type of an incoming function call---------------------
RFC_SYNCHRONOUS = 0 
RFC_TRANSACTIONAL = 1 
RFC_QUEUED = 2 
RFC_BACKGROUND_UNIT = 3 

#-RFC_DIRECTION - Direction of a function module parameter--------------
RFC_IMPORT = 1 
RFC_EXPORT = 2 
RFC_CHANGING = RFC_IMPORT + RFC_EXPORT 
RFC_TABLES = 4 + RFC_CHANGING 

#-RFC_CLASS_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE - Type of an ABAP object attribute-----------
RFC_CLASS_ATTRIBUTE_INSTANCE = 0 
RFC_CLASS_ATTRIBUTE_CLASS = 1 
RFC_CLASS_ATTRIBUTE_CONSTANT = 2 

#-RFC_METADATA_OBJ_TYPE - Ingroup repository----------------------------
RFC_METADATA_FUNCTION = 0 
RFC_METADATA_TYPE = 1 
RFC_METADATA_CLASS = 2 


#-Variables-------------------------------------------------------------
ErrInf = RFC_ERROR_INFO; RfcErrInf = ErrInf()
ConnParams = RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER * 5; RfcConnParams = ConnParams()
SConParams = RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER * 3; RfcSConParams = SConParams()


#-Library---------------------------------------------------------------
if str(platform.architecture()[0]) == "32bit":
  os.environ['PATH'] += ";/home/marilan/Nunes/Klyra/nwrfcsdk/lib"
  SAPNWRFC = "/home/marilan/nwrfcsdk/lib/libsapnwrfc.so"
elif str(platform.architecture()[0]) == "64bit":
  os.environ['PATH'] += ";/home/marilan/Nunes/Klyra/nwrfcsdk/lib"
  SAPNWRFC = "/home/marilan/nwrfcsdk/lib/libsapnwrfc.so"

SAP = cdll.LoadLibrary(SAPNWRFC)

#-Prototypes------------------------------------------------------------
SAP.RfcAppendNewRow.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcAppendNewRow.restype = c_void_p

SAP.RfcCloseConnection.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcCloseConnection.restype = c_ulong

SAP.RfcCreateFunction.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcCreateFunction.restype = c_void_p

SAP.RfcCreateFunctionDesc.argtypes = [c_wchar_p, POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcCreateFunctionDesc.restype = c_void_p

SAP.RfcDestroyFunction.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcDestroyFunction.restype = c_ulong

SAP.RfcDestroyFunctionDesc.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcDestroyFunctionDesc.restype = c_ulong

SAP.RfcGetChars.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_wchar_p, c_void_p, c_ulong, \
  POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcGetChars.restype = c_ulong

SAP.RfcGetCurrentRow.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcGetCurrentRow.restype = c_void_p

SAP.RfcGetFunctionDesc.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_wchar_p, POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcGetFunctionDesc.restype = c_void_p

SAP.RfcGetRowCount.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(c_ulong), \
  POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcGetRowCount.restype = c_ulong

SAP.RfcGetStructure.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_wchar_p, \
  POINTER(c_void_p), POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcGetStructure.restype = c_ulong

SAP.RfcGetTable.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_wchar_p, POINTER(c_void_p), \
  POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcGetTable.restype = c_ulong

SAP.RfcGetVersion.argtypes = [POINTER(c_ulong), POINTER(c_ulong), \
  POINTER(c_ulong)]
SAP.RfcGetVersion.restype = c_wchar_p

SAP.RfcInstallServerFunction.argtypes = [c_wchar_p, c_void_p, \
  c_void_p, POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcInstallServerFunction.restype = c_ulong

SAP.RfcInvoke.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p, POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcInvoke.restype = c_ulong

SAP.RfcListenAndDispatch.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_ulong, POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcListenAndDispatch.restype = c_ulong

SAP.RfcMoveToFirstRow.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcMoveToFirstRow.restype = c_ulong

SAP.RfcMoveToNextRow.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcMoveToNextRow.restype = c_ulong

SAP.RfcOpenConnection.argtypes = [POINTER(ConnParams), c_ulong, \
  POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcOpenConnection.restype = c_void_p

SAP.RfcPing.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcPing.restype = c_ulong

SAP.RfcRegisterServer.argtypes = [POINTER(SConParams), c_ulong, \
  POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcRegisterServer.restype = c_void_p

SAP.RfcSetChars.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_wchar_p, c_wchar_p, c_ulong, \
  POINTER(ErrInf)]
SAP.RfcSetChars.restype = c_ulong
```

Code of function `connection():`

```
from sapnwrfc import *

def connection():
    FileName = "sapnwrfc.py"
    exec(compile(open(FileName).read(), FileName, "exec"))
    #-Main------------------------------------------------------------------

    #-Connection parameters-------------------------------------------------
    RfcConnParams[0].name = "ASHOST"; RfcConnParams[0].value = "I put my credentials here"
    RfcConnParams[1].name = "SYSNR" ; RfcConnParams[1].value = "I put my credentials here"
    RfcConnParams[2].name = "CLIENT"; RfcConnParams[2].value = "I put my credentials here"
    RfcConnParams[3].name = "USER"  ; RfcConnParams[3].value = "I put my credentials here"
    RfcConnParams[4].name = "PASSWD"; RfcConnParams[4].value = "I put my credentials here"

    return RfcConnParams
```

Comment: Try `hRFC = SAP.RfcOpenConnection(byref(connection()), 5, RfcErrInf)`.  But since the 2nd parameter is the size changing `SAP.RfcOpenConnection.argtypes = [POINTER(ConnParams), c_ulong, POINTER(ErrInf)]` to `SAP.RfcOpenConnection.argtypes = [POINTER(RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER), c_ulong, POINTER(ErrInf)]` is probably more appropriate.  Functions normally take an element pointer and a size, not a "pointer to an array of 5 elements" and a size.

Comment: did not work :(, still with the same problem.

Comment: `os.environ['PATH'] += ";/home/marilan/Nunes/Klyra/nwrfcsdk/lib"` check if all those directories where you search your libraries do exist and valid. Most likely your code cannot find the nwrfc installation